# How to save data in private and can't be deleted by clear data in settings

Tags: android, data-persistence

I know there are couples of way to save data for application in android recommend by Google, such as SharePreference, SQLite, Storage [data-storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

But, the data store by those methods will be delete once user clear data in application detail in settings.

I prefer to save data in Settings.Global or Settings.Secure, but I don't know it can feasible, as the API said:"**Applications can read these but are not allowed to write**".

```
    /**
 * Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply identically
 * to all defined users.  Applications can read these but are not allowed to write;
 * like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must
 * explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values.
 */
public static final class Global extends NameValueTable {
```

Comment: Would be better if you tell us what data are you going to store and how sensitive it is

Comment: save data such as the password set by user, which can't be delete by others who use user's cellular phone.

Answer (score 0):

Just save date in a file which is stored in sdcard
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: I don't suppose that this is I am looking for. There are a couple of fields value to store, it seems that there is not convenient API to store and retrieve the data, and I need to confirm weather there is sdcard or not.